# image file is truncated (bytes not processed)

Tags: python, image, image-resizing

I was trying to read a batch of images in Python and resize them. It gives error as in the title, which I think is because the images are in different sizes. How do I solve this? The code is as following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
for x in range(1,10):
    fin = 'path/image%03d.jpg'%(x,)
    im = Image.open(fin)
    im1 = im.resize((400,400),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    fout = 'path/resize/image%03d.jpg'%(x,)
    im1.save(fout)
```

Comment: can you provide full traceback?